# Auto instantiation of member function template for a known set of types in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am trying to explicitly instantiate a member function template, to keep its definition out of the header. The types that need to be instantiated for are the alternative types of an `std::variant` instantiation.
I would like to avoid typing all the explicit instantiations in the source file.

Minimum exposition code:

Header:

```cpp
#include <variant>

using VarType = std::variant<bool, int, float>;
class VarHolder
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    const T* get() const;
private:
    VarType var;
};
```

Source:

```cpp
// A trivial function, for demonstration only
template<typename T>
const T* VarHolder::get() const
{
    if (std::holds_alternative<T>(var))
        return &std::get<T>(var);
    return nullptr;
}

// manual instantiations, which i'd like to avoid,
// since I need to keep these in sync with the definition of VarType
//template const bool*  VarHolder::get<bool>() const;
//template const int*   VarHolder::get<int>() const;
//template const float* VarHolder::get<float>() const;
```

---

## My attempts

So far I've come up with two possible solutions:

- Define a function that calls all required instantiations

```cpp
template<class T>
struct F;

template<class ...Ts>
struct F<std::variant<Ts...>> {
    static void f() {
        VarHolder t{};
        ((t.get<Ts>()), ...);
    }
};

template struct F<VarType>; // actual instantiation
```

This works in MSVC 2022 (C++17). I'm able to include the header and call all the instantiations of `VarHolder::get()`, without getting linker errors. However I doubt it's the optimal way.

- Storing function pointers.

Since I'm not familiar with member function pointers, I decided to create a wrapper function template, which will call the `get()` method for some type.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void fn(const VarHolder& t)
{
    t.get<T>();
}
using fn_t = decltype(&fn<int>); // should be void (*)(const VarHolder&)

template<typename T>
struct S;

template<typename ...Ts>
struct S<std::variant<Ts...>> {
    constexpr static fn_t arr[]{ (&fn<Ts>)... }; // store pointers to all instantiations of fn()
};

template struct S<VarType>; // actual instantiation
```

This doesn't work in MSVC 2022. I get a linker error if calling `VarHolder::get()` elsewhere.

---

## Questions:

1. Is the 1st method actually portable? Is a conforming compiler allowed to not instantiate?
2. Why does the 2nd method fail? I thought taking function pointers should force instantiate the function template.
3. Is there a more elegant/portable way to achieve my goal?

Comment: One question per post. C++ templates are a complex topic. Asking so many question in one post is not recommended,

Comment: Why are you trying to split the template between header an source in the first place, and what is so bad about explicitly instantiating?

Comment: *"This works in MSVC 2022..."* **No it won't/can't** as `template S<VarType>;` is invalid.

Comment: Also the use of explicit instantiation in the first place looks unnecessary(and bad). Just implement templates in the header to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: @user12002570 There is absolutely nothing wrong whatsoever with explicit instantiation.

Comment: @JanSchultke While I agree the above exposition code is too trivial to be considered moving to the source, it can become more complex in a real-world project, where separating the implementation could reduce compilation time for the consumer of the class, or it's just undesired to expose the implementation. Additionally, I thought this member function only makes sense for a fixed set of types, so it's not that "generic". Anyway, I'm just trying to explore the possibilities of C++ templates.

Comment: I think the question is crystal-clear - how to iterate over variant types to explicitly instantiate function(s). And I can imagine some good reasons to do it.

Comment: @JanSchultke As for why not manually instantiate: The alternative types of the `std::variant` might change in the future. With a working solution as asked, I don't need to keep the source and the header in sync manually

Comment: @user12002570 Sorry, It didn't compile with clang. I've edited the code. Strangely, MSVC did compile without errors.

Comment: I had MSVC often accept and compileproperly *completely* wrong code with template explicit instantiation., in onecase even syntax was wrong - result of bad copy/paste.  When GCC discarded it, I re-read code and realized that it could work, at all. How it guessed what I wanted,I don't know - it passed tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly instantiate the member function template.

> A definition of a function template, member function of a class template, variable template, or static data member of a class template shall be reachable from the end of every definition domain ([basic.def.odr]) in which it is implicitly instantiated ([temp.inst]) **unless the corresponding specialization is explicitly instantiated ([temp.explicit]) in some translation unit**; no diagnostic is required.

- [[temp.pre] p10](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#10)

You're trying to "cheat the system" by generating explicit instantiations implicitly, but that's not possible.
`template F<VarType>;` (which should be `template class F<VarType>`) attempts to explicitly instantiate `F`, which then generates all those explicit instantiations for you.
However, this is not portable. If it works, it works because MSVC is unnecessarily aggressive when it comes to transitive explicit instantiations.

[[temp.explicit] p10](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#10) states that only the direct non-template members will be explicitly instantiated when a class template is instantiated.
`f` is obviously not a direct non-template member of `F`, so this approach won't work.

Taking addresses of function templates by forming a function pointer is also not an explicit instantiation, so this would violate the first quote.

### Minimal reproducible example

Let's look at an example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo() {}

template <typename T>
struct S {
    S() { foo<T>(); }
};

template struct S<int>;
```

This explicit instantiation of `S` also includes an implicit instantiation of `foo<int>()`.
The generated assembly from GCC or Clang includes only: (https://godbolt.org/z/orffnM7eT)

```
S<int>::S() [base object constructor]:
        ret
```

MSVC does emit `foo<int>` for some reason, but I wouldn't rely on it.
If only `S<int>` is emitted and `foo<int>` is inlined and not found in the assembly, you get a linker error when calling `foo<int>` from another object file, since it doesn't exist.

Presumably, that's why your second method gives you a linker error.

#### Workaround using macros

```cpp
// header: define the type list and the variant type
#define VAR_HOLDER_VARIANT_TYPE_LIST(F, S) \
  F(bool) S() F(int) S() F(float)

#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define COMMA()       ,

using VarType = std::variant<VAR_HOLDER_VARIANT_TYPE_LIST(IDENTITY, COMMA)>;
```

```cpp
// source: define all explicit instantiations
#define EXPLICITLY_INSTANTIATE_VAR_HOLDER_GET(...) \
  template const __VA_ARGS__* VarHolder::get<__VA_ARGS__>() const

#define SEMICOLON() ;

VAR_HOLDER_VARIANT_TYPE_LIST(EXPLICITLY_INSTANTIATE_VAR_HOLDER_GET, SEMICOLON);
```

Macros are ugly, but at least you don't repeat yourself.
When changing the types of the variant, you only have to update `VAR_HOLDER_VARIANT_TYPE_LIST`.
The rest stays the same.

Answer (score 4):

```
template struct F<VarType>; // actual instantiation
```

This is not a valid declaration. Moreover, instantiating a class template does not automatically instantiate its non-virtual member functions, and implicitly instantiating a template doesn't mean it can be used in other TUs.

But this can be fixed *in practice*. The standard says it is undefined behaviour, but it works with all mainstream implementations. Given the state-of-the-art template and linker technology it is unlikely that it will be broken in the near future, but no guarantees.

```
#include <tuple>
template<class ...Ts>
struct F<std::variant<Ts...>> {
      static constexpr std::tuple fptrs { (&VarHolder::get<Ts>)...};
};

auto fptrs = F<VarType>::fptrs;
```

Here we have an externally visible `fptrs` that contains honest callable pointers to member functions. The compiler has to make these pointers point to something. So we force it to emit machine code for the instantiations, and these get exported as any other instantiation, explicit or implicit, would.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ks6s8arb8)

An implementation that emits different kinds of symbols for explicit and implicit instantiations, or does some kind of whole-program just-in-time compilation, might break this.

Comment: Btw you can use `std::get_if` to simplify `get()` in your demo. That also makes MSVC spit out assembly that's not quite as bloated. Since `fptrs` is an external linkage object in a source file, you can also easily run into ODR violations with this solution. Internal linkage would break your approach, and forward-declaring it in a header defeats the purpose, so you need a ridiculously disambiguated name to prevent this as well. Something like `var_holder_fptrs_helper_object`.

Comment: It's still plausible that a linker distinguishes references which require an entity to exist, and "weak references". In such a case `fptrs` could be optimized out, including all of its contents, and including the instantiated templates. I don't think any common linkers implement this stuff though. It's also plausible that implicit instantiations get mangled differently from explicit instantiations. In any case, I'm curious how robust this approach is.

Comment: @JanSchultke "external linkage object in a source file" what's wrong with that? Of course in practice you would hide it (and also `F`) within some uniquely named namespace.

Comment: No, you can't hide it in an unnamed namespace. If you do that, then `fptrs` is going to be unused and will get optimized out, including everything else. It must have external linkage and be non-inline. The problem with external linkage is that `fptrs` defined in some other TU would mean that you're defining `fptrs` twice with different meanings, and that's an ODR violation. In practice, you might get a linker error.

Comment: @JanSchultke I don't think `fptrs` can be optimized out in any scenario. There is nothing wrong with a pointer to an implicitly instantiated template, or to a weak symbol. Different mangling is possible in theory but I think it needs linker support. At some point the linker will have to merge all implicit and explicit instantiations of the same function to a single one. Re. namespaces: not unnamed, just unique.

Comment: It obviously can be optimized out. See for yourself https://godbolt.org/z/rbdde9Ts5

Comment: But you put it in an unnamed namespace. Did I say or imply anywhere that you can do that?

Comment: Yes, you've said "in any scenario". Is the scenario where it's in an unnamed namespace not a scenario? I've been trying to explain for quite few comments that internal linkage is necessary to avoid ODR violations, but that would also break this whole approach.

Comment: No, in any scenario doesn't mean you are free to change the code. I obviously cannot guarantee that any code you invent will work. In any scenario means an implementation is free to change its strategies.

Comment: Well then you're also wrong. An implementation could do whole-program analysis and see that `fptrs` is not used, resulting in it getting optimized out.

Comment: @JanSchultke An implementation that can do a whole program analysis and detect that the variable is unused can do that. But in a world where dynamic linking is the norm such an implementation is unlikely to exist, because you cannot ever define what the "whole program" is.